# Find lines in one Object based on strings in other object

Tags: powershell, powershell-v5.1, pattern-finding

Finding lines in one file based on rows in another file.

I have one object `$A` with some rows like:

```
0c7d3283-bec2-4db1-9078-ebb79d21afdf
200bc957-26dd-4e8e-aa6e-00dc357c4ac2
218e0d2a-0e8b-4a68-8136-8f5dd749a614
```

I want to find matches in object `$B` for those rows and print the lines with the matches to an output file.

I've been trying for a week now (my first week in powershell :) )
I've come to:

```
$F = $B | ForEach-Object{ $A | Select-String -Pattern $_$ -AllMatches| Select-Object line }
```

but this doesn't give me any returning results.

Who is willing to help me out?

Comment: if your objects are simple strings, then all you need it the `-in` or `-contains` operator in a `Where-Object` or `.Where({})` method filter. something like this ... `$1stCollection.Where({$_ -in $2ndCollection}` will give you the items in the 1st that are also in the 2nd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match your first Array, with something that should match part of a string in a second array you do something like the code below:

```
$A = @("0c7d3283-bec2-4db1-9078-ebb79d21afdf", "200bc957-26dd-4e8e-aa6e-00dc357c4ac2", "218e0d2a-0e8b-4a68-8136-8f5dd749a614")

$B = @("Something 0c7d3283-bec2-4db1-9078-ebb79d21afdf", "Something else 200bc957-26dd-4e8e-aa6e-00dc357c4ac2", "Something also e3df3978-beb7-4545-bc48-ff40d8453be1")

foreach ($Line in $A) {
    if($B -match $Line) {
        $B | Where-Object {$_ -match $Line}
    }
}
```

We first loop through all the lines in the first object, then compare if the line is matched to anything in the second array. If we find a match we go through Array B to find where the Line from A matches.

You could make this code a hell lot prettier, but this the most understandable way I can write it.

**Old Answer**
You could use the `Compare-Object` cmdlet to compare the two arrays, then use the `-IncludeEqual` switch to show where there are matches and then use the `-ExcludeDifferent` switch to remove the results that do not match.
Then take that Output and put in in a file. A simple test could be something like this:

```
$A = @("0c7d3283-bec2-4db1-9078-ebb79d21afdf", "200bc957-26dd-4e8e-aa6e-00dc357c4ac2", "218e0d2a-0e8b-4a68-8136-8f5dd749a614")

$B = @("0c7d3283-bec2-4db1-9078-ebb79d21afdf", "200bc957-26dd-4e8e-aa6e-00dc357c4ac2", "e3df3978-beb7-4545-bc48-ff40d8453be1")


(Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $A -DifferenceObject $B -ExcludeDifferent -IncludeEqual).InputObject | Out-File .\output.txt
```

This should output a file in your Shells current working directory with the two GUIDs that match:

```
0c7d3283-bec2-4db1-9078-ebb79d21afdf
200bc957-26dd-4e8e-aa6e-00dc357c4ac2
```

Where the one that didn't match is not included.

Comment: If you append `-ExcludeDifferent` to `Compare-Object `you could drop the `|Where ...` (+1)

Comment: @LotPings you are correct, must have my head under my shoulder after all the Christmas food this holiday season :). I have edited my answer with your suggestion.

Comment: Thanks @HenrikStanleyMortensen I'm very impressed. But I'm afraid my specs aren't 100% clear. Sorry for that. $A is correct, but $B is more like lines with sometimes one of the codes of $A in it. f.i.   abced12350c7d3283-bec2-4db1-9078-ebb79d21afdfsome more text.   another line 3a4d5g3f-gea1-4er2-1112-aeb22e3asdf wrong code even_more tekst.  So I like to see only those lines with the code included.

Comment: @marceluitnederland I have edited my answer. You could use the outputted objects to append to a file, or collect them in an array and then add them all to a file when you have the entire array if you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot @HenrikStanleyMortensen, you made a quit 3th Christmasday very enjoyable.